# how to create a model after a devise registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a user registration with an extra field called "company_name". After the user gets created, I want a Company instance to be created based on the extra field "company_name" and that user associated with the company. I've tried a few things like this:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    super
    company = Company.create(name: params[:company_name])
    current_user.admin = true
    current_user.company = company
    current_user.save
  end

  def update
    super
  end
end
```

however, I don't have a current_user when trying to do the lines after I create the company. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizing the [`after_save`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_save) callback in `User` model is probably suitable for this case:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  # Execute this callback after an record is saved only on create
  after_save :create_and_associate_company, on: :create

  private:

  def create_and_associate_company
    company = self.companies.build
    # Other necessary attributes assignments

    company.save
  end    
end
```

Reference on other [`Active Record Callbacks`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

Comment: i was thinking about this but how would I have access to the necessary parameter since params[:company_name] won't be available in the model (it isn't being saved to the user).

Comment: If it's just one attribute for company name then adding a virtual attribute `company_name` in `User` model might be a good option.  However if you intend to use multiple attribute for company then a nested model form might be the way to go.

Comment: would you mind explaining how the nested model form would work?

Comment: Please take a look at: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: This can be problematic because a company might already exist for the given name. That might need to result in an error in the sign-up process, but now this user is already created and would need to be deleted, and the controller return a proper validation error. IMO overriding the create on the Devise controller would be a better place to handle this.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a block to the Devise controller's `create` that will give you the created user resource:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  CREATE_COMPANY_PARAMS = [:name]

  def create
    super do |created_user|
      if created_user.id
        company = Company.create! create_company_params
        created_user.update! company_id: company.id
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def create_company_params
    params.require(:user).require(:company).permit(*CREATE_COMPANY_PARAMS)
  end
end
```

There are some tough parts to handling this correctly though.
It seems that even if the user already exists, it will still call your block and pass you a user, but the user won't have an `id` assigned because the DB save failed. The `if created_user.id` check prevents a company from being created for an invalid user.

If the company already exists. The `.create!` will throw an exception which causes the controller to return an HTTP 422.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the newly created user using the `resource` variable

Here, I'm logging info only if the user was actually saved

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

    def create
        super

        if resource.persisted?
            Rails.logger.info("Just created and saved #{resource}");
        end
    end
end
```